# How to modify Rails 3 form builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, formbuilder, alias-method-chain

What is the best way to override `form_for`?

For example, in every `form_for(@post)`,

I would like to automatically set the `<form>` id attribute to `@post.object_id`,

and add the following field: `hidden_field_tag :form_id, @post.object_id`

Can I do this using `alias_method_chain`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, you could probably achieve your goal by using `alias_method_chain`, but it would require parsing the form and injecting/modifying the content, which could get really ugly, really fast.

Instead, I'd suggest overriding `form_for` with your own custom version (the original source can be seen here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for by clicking "show source" at the bottom).

One way to achieve this is described in a post I wrote recently: http://davidsulc.com/blog/2011/05/01/self-marking-required-fields-in-rails-3/

The difference being: instead of overriding the `label` method, you'll be rewriting the `form_for` method.

P.S.: out of curiosity, why do you need to expose the `object_id`?

Comment: Are there any issues with using object_id?

Comment: Well, `object_id` is basically Ruby's internal business. There are few cases in Ruby where you need to use `object_id`, and I can't think of a reason why you'd need to expose it in Rails. Also, for a given database record, `oject_id` will basically be different each time it is loaded into memory (you can try that by calling `Post.first.object_id` repeatedly in the Rails console). I'm just thinking that there might be a better way to achieve your goal (whatever it may be) than using the `object_id` attribute...

Answer (score 2):

This should work (it worked for me):

```
  <%= hidden_field(:post :form_id, :value => @post.object_id) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Rails helper you can simply do something like:

```
def form_for(record, options = {}, &block)
  options[:id] = record.class.to_s + '-' + record.id
  super
end
```